# SQLite onCreate exception

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, exception

I have no idea what is happening. Any clues?

```
11-05 18:02:01.195: D/dalvikvm(641): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-05 18:02:01.595: E/Trace(641): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-05 18:02:01.907: E/SQLiteLog(641): (1) near "Table": syntax error
11-05 18:02:01.915: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
11-05 18:02:01.915: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cookbook.adiel/com.cookbook.adiel.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Stories Table(row id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Story name TEXT,Recipe ingredients TEXT,Clean recipe TEXT, )
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Stories Table(row id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Story name TEXT,Recipe ingredients TEXT,Clean recipe TEXT, )
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.cookbook.adiel.StoryDatabaseHandler.onCreate(StoryDatabaseHandler.java:40)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.cookbook.adiel.StoryDatabaseHandler.addStory(StoryDatabaseHandler.java:55)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.cookbook.adiel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-05 18:02:01.925: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the onCreate method, so here it is.
Database Handler onCreate method:

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Stories Table";

// table column names
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "row id";
private static final String KEY_STORYNAME = "Story name";
private static final String KEY_INGREDIENTS = "Recipe ingredients";
private static final String KEY_RECIPE = "Clean recipe";

public StoryDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_STORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STORYNAME
            + " TEXT," + KEY_INGREDIENTS + " TEXT," + KEY_RECIPE + " TEXT,"
            + " )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_STORIES_TABLE);
}
```

If it's something else, I'll put what is requested.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your table name is `Stories Table`. Change it to something like `StoriesTable`.
And of course change columns names also.

Comment: Change columns names also and remove last comma from statement.

Comment: Now it's not giving me any errors, it just posts 
"11-05 19:23:09.951: D/dalvikvm(640): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 6% free 6631K/7047K, paused 29ms+21ms, total 105ms"
kinds of messages, infinitely

Comment: Where do I view the items inside the database?

Comment: This is the answer for your question about exception you were getting. If you have other questions then accept this answer and ask a new question.